# Как по ip открыть веб-сервер?

Tags: ip, android

У меня есть компьютер, на нем запущен Денвер и есть эмулятор. Как мне на эмуляторе Андроида зайти на сервак по ip

Comment: Через браузер?

Comment: ip ввести в адресной строке не получается?

Comment: ну да, потом :порт если не стандартный

Comment: что пишет?

Comment: а IP белый?))

Comment: порт 8080 стандартный

Comment: Попробуй 127.0.0.1 сначала проверь) Если открывается значит проблема либо с фаерволом, либо с тем что IP серый...

Comment: на компе все ок, а в эмуляторе не открывется пишет веб-станица не доступна

Comment: а в эмуляторе все настройки прописаны?

Comment: С эмулятора заходи на ip компа

Comment: не заходит, напиши ответ какой-нибудь, то тут не коментов много писаьт нельзя

Comment: не заходит

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Кажется, здесь вам всё описано: [Android Emulator и локальный веб-сервер (Denwer)](http://habrahabr.ru/post/120671/).
Адрес компа в эмуляторе 10.0.2.2.